# What is an efficient way of removing thick grout haze?

Tags: tile, grout

I have replaced a cracked tile in my kitchen and have set the grout accordingly. I must have missed a step because the haze (which is supposed to come up with a cheese cloth) is more like London fog, and is not coming up without significant effort.

Surely there has to be a better way to get (very thick) haze off the surface of a tile?

I have a Dremel and it was *very* helpful for removing the old grout- is there a relatively soft polish/brush bit I can use?

(Fortunately the tile appears to be pretty heavy duty, so I am less concerned about scratching the glaze than I am about removing the excess grout.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A Scotch Brite pad has always worked for me.  If you are dealing with a large area, use a random orbital sander with a Scotch Brite attachment and the universal lubricant, water.

[image]

Comment: This was the most approachable solution (as my tile isn't smooth, otherwise the blade would have sufficed, I'm sure) and worked like a charm. Three cheers for Scotch Brite and water!

Comment: Glad you found it useful.

Answer (score 2):

You need to keep it wet.  I use vinegar water solution and try to let it sit on the tile for a good 10-20 mins.  Scoop it up and repeat.  If you are polishing it dry you will make it worse (or no better).

Also next time take a heavy dawn/water mix and rub it on your tile before you grout.  When it is dry then you grout.  And your grout slides off the tile.

Answer (score 1):

An amateur tile installer did not do any haze removal in our new shower.  Alas, it was epoxy-based grout.

I tried vinegar, CLR, TSP, alcohol, water, and all kinds of "miracle" cleaning tools.  The best was a plain $1.80 [razor scraper](http://www.homedepot.com/p/Stanley-1-1-2-in-Razor-Scraper-28-500/202262010#.Ug4_sk2AUkA) plus time:  approximately 80 hours (a few hours each evening for more than a month).  In my case, it worked well because the tile had a mirror smooth finish.  And the time spent was quite meditative and therapeutic.

If there had been any surface texture on the tile, I don't know what I would have done.  Maybe bust out all the tile and do it again.

[image: razor scraper image]